# Effects of metallic skin in close combat

Tags: medieval, martial-arts

Royal guards paraljia undergoes a ritual at the end of their training. This antic ritual transforms their body variety of metals and rocks ( similar to colossus from x-men) After this crucial ritual they become  elite forces of empire.

How would this effect their fighting style. what weapons they would use. Should they need shields.

(The metals-rocks they have in their body doesn't effect their stamina by the way. They have thicker skin than both human skin and a plate armor

Comment: What sort of metals and rocks did you have in mind? Obviously tin and sandstone are a bit less desirable than steel and granite, so I'd presume the latter but its always nice to be clear. Is their whole body transmuted, or just the skin? Can they still heal or regenerate damage?

Comment: It is dependent on their personality and because they are mostly trained warriors it is mostly durable metrals like iron steel concrete or titanium alloys. It is only skin but it helps them heal any physical damage

Comment: Also, what is the tech level of this society? Modern? Medieval? Bronze age?

Comment: It is medieval but they have advenced mines and forges. So there are high quality steel and alloys. (The forges are magical)

Answer (score 9):

> How would this effect their fighting style.

A lot less than you might think. The nice thing about armour and weapons is that they can be rapidly replaced if damaged, or swapped according to specific needs. It's hard to change your skin very often! With a Wolverine-like super healing power, your peeps will be still be vulnerable to damage in combat, and the nature of human biomechanics means that you *cannot* have super thick armour everywhere, and even if there was, there's no space for padding, too. This means they should still act with caution, certainly they should not do anything more reckless than a regular meatbag in plate armour, as anything that will drop a regular man-at-arms will finish them off, too.

You've specified thicker skin, though not gone into detail. There are obviously several limits here... Firstly, human biomechanics being what they are, joints will always be vulnerable. Skin is limited in its thickness there, because there's simply no space for it to fold up neatly. Unless you condemn your soldiers to a lifetime of clumsiness, their fingers must necessarily be thinly-armoured, Armpits and elbows, kneepits and the groin will likewise need to have thin, flexible coverings, and those places are very vulnerable to damage as there are major blood vessels and delicate nerves under the surface. Your peeps will still need to wear armour over these areas in real combat.

Regular armour also has a *lot* of padding underneath to absorb the impact of blows and prevent dents in armour impinging on flesh and bone underneath. Your guys can't have this... there's no space! Under their armour skin will be a thin layer of fat, and under that will be muscle, bone, organs and all the rest. Denting their skin will be crippling as the muscle underneath will be crushed, and the bone underneath broken. Blows to the head could cause traumatic brain injury even without cracking the skull, so even a metal skull won't remove the need for a decent helmet.

They'll be pretty resistant to many projectile weapons, though they probably shouldn't charge a line of crossbowmen armed with high-poundage bows and quarrels.

They'd make *excellent* bodyguards, police or paramilitary units, because most of the opponents they'd face would be lightly armed and armoured at best, ill-equipped to penetrate metal skin and rapidly stopped by a few quick jabs from a literal iron fist.

They'll be *heavy*. That'll have a big effect on unarmed combat. They'll have the full weight of all that steel behind a punch, and they'll be quite difficult to throw and *very* dangerous if they were on top of your in a wrestling situation.

Conversely, on softer terrain they'll sink into the ground a lot more than a normal or more lightly armoured human, making them more vulnerable. They'll need big, strong horses to carry them, if they wish to ride on horseback, and they might not be able to ride on horses *at all* if they also wore auxiliary armour.

> what weapons they would use.

Probably the same sort of weapons that their society would use against regular humans wearing armour. Maybe heavier swords, but flanged maces and warhammers would probably be more effective against their peers and against well armoured opponents.

Probably best not to try bare-handed fighting against an armed opponent though. The skin on the palm of your hands is thick, thick enough to grab a sharp blade and disarm its wielder, but don't try catching a swung sword if you value your fingers which can still get bent, crushed and broken. *Definitely* don't muck about against anyone wielding weapons that work well against armour, like the aforementioned flanged maces and warhammers.

> Should they need shields

I'd say so. They're quite damage resistant compared to their fellow normal meatbags, but they're still quite vulnerable even to the weapons wielded by those meatbags. They not only need shields, but also armour. It might not have to be as substantial as a normal knight or man-at-arms, but something is needed or they'll get bashed out of shape and beaten to death.

Comment: They should be excellent in close combat against unarmed fighting styles that favour hard strikes, but much less effective against those that favour locks and holds.

Comment: @JoeBloggs its slightly hard to quantify that one... they could reasonably be describe as armed at all times, and it would be a brave grappler who tried wrestling with someone who can punch, kick and headbutt hard enough to break bones.

Comment: Google says it is 2 mm in normal humans I would say they would have near 6 mm of extra skin. As a metal. They are no wolverine but they could heal a bone in a day or two

Comment: @AIwithstick these details need to go _in the question_. As you can see, they are important!

Comment: @JoeBloggs a weapon will almost always provide a benefit to unarmed combat, it's why humans have used weapons instead of bare fists since the stone age

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid it will an adverse effect: you mention their skin is thicker than plate armor, this means that once turned into metal/stone it will prevent any movement and they will turn into nice statues.

At that point nobody will bother fighting them, since they can only arm people by being toss onto them.

Just to understand why I say this, think of what happens when a cast is poured around a broken bone covering the joint: it gets immobilized. You are doing the same on the whole body.

Comment: It is a inner metal not outer. So their body doesn't get ticker. Also the metals doesn't fully harden. it becomes a stronger skin

Comment: @AIwithstick, what does it change? Rock and metal do not flex.

Comment: Let's say they are in a fase between solid and liquid so they are durable and flexible

Answer (score 1):

This is a hot take but I don't think it would be much different combat found in the European Middle Ages in regards to unmounted knights. To take down an armored target, generally the best strategy is to use blunt force rather than penetration. Long Swords, Axes, Clubs, Maces, and Hammers were very effective against armored targets. To combat this most armor had an under-layer of heavy cloth in an attempt to stop some force being transferred directly from the armor to the wearers body.

When plate armor became the standard for knights, most did not carry shields, however most of the combatants in a middle ages battlefield did not have armor and did not give up using a shield.

Against ranged weaponry: military historians have found that small to medium sized bows were ineffective against plate armor, however crossbows and longbows were able to penetrate.

Like unmounted knights. Your metal guards wouldn't fare well against mounted troops. Mounted troops excelled at delivery high energy blunt impacts at high speed.

I'm not sure if your world will incorporate real life nations or nations based on them but compared to most of the dominant nations in real life but hopefully this gives some insight:

7th Century - Arabs were highly successful utilizing camel infantry to outmanuever larger forces, which were mainly focused on heavy infantry and heavy cavalry.

11th Century - Vikings found great with light infantry and guerrilla style raiding. The typical raider would be unarmored and carry a knife, a spear, and a shield.

13th Century - Mongols very successful with large scale cavalry raiding. Eventually were stopped by extensive fortifications built by the Hungarians and Poles.